# TypeError: 'Route' object is not subscriptable Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

This is a script I have that reads a JSON file and adds routes to a graph

```
 for route in data['routes']:
        route = Route(route['ports'][0], route['ports'][1], route['distance'])
        self.add_route(route)
        route_2 = Route (route['ports'][1], route['ports'][0], route['distance'])
        self.add_route(route_2)
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\Assignment2.1\src\Main.py", line 75, in <module>
    graph.build_from_file()
  File "C:\workspace\Assignment2.1\src\Graph.py", line 195, in build_from_file
    route_2 = Route (route['ports'][1], route['ports'][0], route['distance'])
TypeError: 'Route' object is not subscriptable
```

Notice it gives an error at the second call of the Route constructor not first.
Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 4):

You named two different things `route`.

After you created your first `Route`, the `route` variable is pointing to it instead of your datum.

Fixed code:

```
for route in data['routes']:
    route_1 = Route(route['ports'][0], route['ports'][1], route['distance'])
    self.add_route(route_1)
    route_2 = Route(route['ports'][1], route['ports'][0], route['distance'])
    self.add_route(route_2)
```